# Angular UI-Router loading controller only when route is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Let's say I have two pages, **cloud** and **settings**. I have the following code set up:

```
var routerApp = angular.module('APP', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/cloud');

    $stateProvider

        .state('cloud', {
            url: '/cloud',
            templateUrl: 'pages/templates/cloud.html',
            controller: 'cloud',
        })

        .state('settings', {
            url: '/settings',
            templateUrl: 'pages/templates/settings.html',
            controller: 'settings'  
        });

});

routerApp.controller('cloud', function($scope, $http, $state) {
    alert("cloud");
});

routerApp.controller('settings', function($scope, $http, $state) {
    alert("settings");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="APP">
    <head>
        <title>TITLE</title>
        <base href="/">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.13/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="navContainer">
            <a ui-sref="cloud">Cloud</a>
            <a ui-sref="settings">Settings</a>
        </div>

        <div id="pageContent">
            <div ui-view></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Regardless of what page I load, settings or cloud, the each controller will run no matter what. Meaning I will get 2 alerts, regardless, when I reload the page.

Could anyone help explain what I need to do so that if I reload my website on `/settings`, only the code in my settings controller will run and vice versa?

Comment: Could you include your html as well please?

Comment: Could you try adding a ')' to the end of each routerApp.Controller section? They're missing.

Comment: accidentally left it out when adding to stack overflow, but I added it @PatrickMotard

Comment: I'm working on a solution.

Comment: What do your view htmls look like?

Comment: The result's are the same regardless of my views. Right now its a blank template. But I could have whatever and the results would be the same. @PatrickMotard

Comment: [Here's a basic example.](http://plnkr.co/edit/u18KQc?p=preview)There may be some differences. I think your views will need to include an `<div ui-view></div>`.

Comment: I don't take offense, it's okay. I understand your frustration. In the example i was able to put a different alert in both scopes and when the page was loaded, only the alert specific to the view i was viewing showed. Also, I wasn't able to see the markup in your settings.html nor cloud.html so I'm not sure if there was a `<div ui-view></div> directive in them or not.

Comment: Here's the same example except with alerts: http://plnkr.co/edit/cLQy3rElNVSBpA0nliQj?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for trying to help @PatrickMotard but I think we are on different wave lengths for this question.

Comment: sounds like you also have controllers declared in `ng-controller` in your partials. If so use one or the other but not both declarations for controller

Comment: @charlietfl I'm not sure what you mean, could you please elaborate? I'm fairly new to angular

Comment: are you using `ng-controller="cloud"` in markup? If so you would be initializing controller twice

Comment: I'm using what you see. I don't use `ng-controller` in my templates or anywhere. My templates are blank. It's not an issue of loading *twice* but more of loading once, even if i'm not on the page it's supposed to be loading on.

Comment: bryan, I tried to reproduce this locally using your files, and was not able to reproduce the error you're referring to.  [Here is a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pB5hu1DTTb7Uc801ZAUA?p=preview).  Plunkr doesn't work with html5mode, so I have removed that and the html base tag, but those were on my local test which worked fine.  Please compare to your local code, and let us know what's different.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your controllers declared in the partials(views) that your router is loading then those controllers will only fire when the view is loaded. It sounds to me like you need a parent controller(s) that will fire to give you logic that can controller both of the views.

Your Code:

```
$stateProvider.state('cloud', {
            url: '/cloud',
            templateUrl: 'pages/templates/cloud.html',
            controller: 'cloud',
        })

        .state('settings', {
            url: '/settings',
            templateUrl: 'pages/templates/settings.html',
            controller: 'settings'  
        });
```

You are setting the controllers there if you would like them to share a controller simply refer to the same controller like so:

```
$stateProvider

    .state('cloud', {
        url: '/cloud',
        templateUrl: 'pages/templates/cloud.html',
        controller: 'shared',
    })

    .state('settings', {
        url: '/settings',
        templateUrl: 'pages/templates/settings.html',
        controller: 'shared'  
    });
```

Comment: This creates 2 instances of the 'shared' controller, not a single shared controller.